# Writing into file with PHP

Tags: php, file, fwrite

What is the problem of this code in PHP?

```
<?php
$f = "log.txt";
$fh = fopen($f, 'a') or die("Can't open log file");
$s = "Test Line\n";
fwrite($f, $s);
fclose($f);
?>
```

The permission of the log.txt is 777.
But `fwrite` can't write anything in it.
What is the problem?

Comment: Are there any errors either on the page or in your error log?

Comment: You open in `$fh` but write to `$f` which is a string

Comment: By the way, try to make verbosely-named variables when trying to find bugs... using variable names like `$f`, `$fh` and `$s` doesn't help

Comment: Tnx a lot. I think I should go to sleep :)))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this...

```
<?php
$f = "log.txt";
$fh = fopen($f, 'a') or die("Can't open log file");
$s = "Test Line\n";
fwrite($fh, $s);
fclose($fh);
?>
```

Actually you are using file name instead of file handle.

Answer (score 3):

You'll like to know about [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php):

```
file_put_contents("log.txt", "Test Line\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: At least I like this :) Thx, haven't heard about that yet.